# viewport equivalent in Cocoa-touch?

Tags: html, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to convert my HTML5/Canvas webgame into a native iOS app. Due to a large number of audio files and Apple's infuriating memory leak issue when dealing with large amounts of audio (I'm using sound and preload js to manage the assets on the web), I find myself having to recreate the whole thing natively, but am running into an issue with automatic scaling. The app itself is 800x600, and I'm using a viewport meta tag to set the scale for the webpage. This approach works well on mobile devices, so I was wondering if there was an equivalent to the viewport tag in Cocoa that would make an 800 x 600 stage appear centred on every current iOS device (4/4s and up)? It would be ideal if there was an equivalent that handled scaling for any size and orientation, but I'd even settle for auto scaling in landscape.

Comment: I'd recommend learning autoLayout, it will allow your controls to scale / shrink

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Will this allow for a static size to be automatically centred on the screen? The original project was done in flash by a third-party, so I do not have access to the original graphical assets (hence my need to automatically scale everything like a viewport tag).

Comment: Yes there are many types of constraints in autoLayout, ones to set a static value to an attribute, such as width or height, others to centre a view based on its parent or another view entirely, pin a view to another with X space in between, align the left edges etc.

Comment: What library do you plan on using? SpriteKit, Cocos2D, Corona...etc? If you are using Cocos2D you can simply create a node and position it accordingly.